# NetSuite fetch list of countries internal ID's

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Is there a way in netsuite to fetch a list of countries with their internal id's ?

There seems to be pre-defined country list with both country codes and internal ids

[https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/71731/kw/country%20internal%20id's](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/71731/kw/country%20internal%20id%27s)

Is it posible to load it as a record or search resault in a suitelet?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember where I downloaded the original list from, but here is a gist that I create a while back.  It is for translating in the Jitterbit iPaaS, but it might be able to give you the data you need?

[Jitterbit - Country/Country Codes to NetSuite Country Format](https://gist.github.com/W3BGUY/5f74250152774d2c8d1dd8dc3246dfee)

Comment: Thanks, i have seen other pre-defined list that you can import to NS, or hard-coded arrays, but what i find strange is that there seems to be no pre-defined country list available for development. My best guess is to search with N'querry for the source table. If i find something i will post it here